# How to get json data properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to get the data inside of `"attributes"` in these json format, but I always get `undefined`

```
{ "data": [ 
   { "attributes":     
      {
         "id":"4977",
         "book_id":"651284829",
         "provider_id":"1",
         "title":"\u96e8\u8272\u30b3\u30b3\u30a2",
         "author":"IAM, K.K.",
         "price":"170.00",
         "rating":"4"
      },
      ...
   }
}
```

This is my code which always returns `undefined`:

```
for ( var obj in json.data) {
    var att = obj.attributes;
    html += "<p>" + att.author + "</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating over the keys of the properties of `json.data`, not the values of those properties.

Change

```
var att = obj.attributes;
```

to

```
var att = json.data[obj].attributes;
```

To make it clearer, a different name could be used :

```
for (var key in json.data) {
    var obj = json.data[key];
    var att = obj.attributes;
    html += "<p>" + att.author + "</p>";
}
```

Comment: To expand upon this, if you use `console.log(obj)` you'll find out that it outputs `attributes` as the only content in the `obj` variable.

Comment: where can I find the output if I use console.log?

Comment: @BryanPosas See [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console). Using the console really changes the like of a JS developer.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for being helpful to a newbie.